# Need to know how to skip over a subfolder in VBScripit

Tags: vbscript, windows-scripting

I am horrible at writing VBScript and I have a question that should be pretty simple for anyone who has any experience writing VBScript code.  I have a script file that parses the file system starting at a specified directory, then doing a recursive search through each subfolder.  The file names, path name, and date modified are then sent to an SQL stored procedure that writes the data to a table.  This is working as described but I need to put a filter on in script to tell the script to ignore any paths ending in PDF_IMAGES\ or TIF_IMAGES. I don't want to process anything in those folders or any subfolders within those folders.  Here is the snippet of what I have so far:

```
Const startDir = "\\myfileshare\images"

'Variables
Dim objFSO, strFolder, subFolder

'Use the FileSystemObject to search directories and create the text file.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Call the Search subroutine to start the recursive search.
Search objFSO.GetFolder(startDir)

Sub Search(sPath)

    'Assign the value of sPath to the strFolder variable.
    strFolder = sPath

    'Use undeclared variable to run function
    strReturnFileNames = FindLatestFileMatchingRegex(strFolder & "\", "*.*" ) 

    strFolder = ""

    'Find EACH SUBFOLDER.
    For Each subFolder In sPath.SubFolders
        'Call the Search subroutine to start the recursive search on EACH SUBFOLDER.
        Search objFSO.GetFolder(subFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Right(subFolder.Path, 7)
```

will give you the last six characters of the path. You then need to compare them to _IMAGES. You can use StrComp for that

```
StrComp("_IMAGES", path)
```

That will give you 0 if they are identical. So something like this (untested) will give you the idea.

```
If Not StrComp("_IMAGES", Right(subFolder.Path, 7)) = 0 then
Search objFSO.GetFolder(subFolder.Path)
End If
```

Here's a [helpful reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to fill in the gaps.

I don't miss vbscript at all

Comment: I'd prefer `Right(subFolder.Name, 7) <> "_IMAGES"`.